# Multilined Label broken with position constraint

Tags: ios, storyboard

In a page of my application, I would like to add a Label text on top of a bottom bar.

I have succeeded that by adding the following constraint:

BottomBarImage.top = Label.bottom + 24

The problem is that the label is planned to show 2-3 lines of text.
I have tested on simulator and the result is only one line is showed.

Important note: By removing the constraint, the lines in Label are shown correctly (but the position of the Label is wrong of course)

How can we fix the multiline issue ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show a bit more of your setup? Additional constraints etc.

Comment: Don't talk _about_ what you are doing. _Show_ what you are doing. Work out in advance what is needed by a stranger to _reproduce_ the issue and show us that in the question.

Comment: Yes you are right. I have added some screenshots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your constraints are insufficient.

A label that is not under auto layout just sits there, inert; at layout time, its size is the size you gave it in the storyboard.

But as soon as you add a constraint to it, the label comes under auto layout. That changes everything. A label under auto layout is *self-sizing*: it automatically adapts to the size of its content. It will automatically adapt to the necessary height, but only if its width is fixed (so that it knows when to wrap). You have not given any *width* constraint for this label, nor have you given it a `preferredMaxLayoutWidth`, so the auto layout engine doesn't know how to do that.

So, to fix this problem, add a width constraint to your label or give it a `preferredMaxLayoutWidth`. Or, if you know both dimensions, give it both a width constraint and a height constraint. (And make sure the `numberOfLines` has been changed to `0`; the default is `1` which is a single line only.)